# c++ how to write to a process that was created with createProcess

Tags: c++, createprocess

I am creating a new Powershell process via createProcess and would like to write a command to that Powershell window and hit Enter. Here is what I have:

```
 #include <cstdio>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <tlhelp32.h>
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
    
        STARTUPINFO si;
        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    
        ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
        si.cb = sizeof(si);
        ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
    
        char myCommand[] = "cmd /c powershell.exe -NoExit";
    
        CreateProcess(NULL,      // No module name (use command line)
                      myCommand, // Command line
                      NULL,      // Process handle not inheritable
                      NULL,      // Thread handle not inheritable
                      FALSE,     // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
                      0,         // No creation flags
                      NULL,      // Use parent's environment block
                      NULL,      // Use parent's starting directory
                      &si,       // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
                      &pi);      // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    
        Sleep(5000);
    
        string strMytestString("ls");
        cout << strMytestString.c_str();
    
        Sleep(2000);
    
        // ENTER key down
        keybd_event(VK_RETURN, 0x9C, 0, 0);
    
        // ENTER key up
        keybd_event(VK_RETURN, 0x9C, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
        return 0;
    }
```

It opens the powershell and writes "ls" into it and hits Enter but Powershell does not take it as a command and does not do the "ls" but write it as a normal text.
Is there a way to make Powershell execute that command that I pass to it as a String?

Answer (score 2):

Try to read a little bit more about STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR.

To achieve your intention, you have to pass commands into STDIN of child process.

Take a look for MSDN post [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output) that shown exactly what you need.

Comment: I get the input in the right programm (powershell-window) but it does not execute it as a command. It just writes "ls" and hits enter without showing the directory. So I have the streams redirected correctly right?

Comment: Yes, you need to stream "ls" into STDIN of child process. This will be same behaviour as typing on keyboard "ls" in PowerShell terminal.